# How can I check the whether a Facebook Page is verified with Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to check whether a Facebook page is verified. I googled it and find out with FQL i can get that information but FQL will be not be available after 2016, and I checked the fields of page node in graph api, i didn't find a field indicate whether this page is verified. Is there an approach that i can achieve my target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field "is_verified" can be requested on any node.

```
GET /v2.1/{PAGE ID}?fields=is_verified HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

This will retrun the following JSON.

```
{
"is_verified": {BOOL}, 
"id": "{NODE ID}"
}
```

A username can also be used in place of the {PAGE ID} such as using "facebook" instead of "20531316728"